# XSLT unable to group/sort nodes based on value

Tags: xslt, sorting, formatting, grouping

I'm trying to transform this xml. However I'm having formatting issues. Could someone please guide me to solve this problem.  Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<XML>
    <Attributes>
        <Attribute>
            <id>5</id>
            <Name>Buyer ID</Name>
            <Type>common</Type>
            <Value>Lee</Value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute>
            <id>331</id>
            <Name>Enviornment</Name>
            <Type>common</Type>
            <Value>Development</Value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute>
            <id>79</id>
            <Name>Retail</Name>
            <Type>common</Type>
            <Value></Value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute>
            <id>402</id>
            <Name>Gender</Name>
            <Type>category</Type>
            <Value>Men</Value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute>
            <id>433</id>
            <Name>HeelHeight</Name>
            <Type>category</Type>
            <Value></Value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute>
            <id>41</id>
            <Name>PlusShip</Name>
            <Type>common</Type>
            <Value>False</Value>
            <Path></Path>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
</XML>
```

Into the following XML. Could someone please give me some tips in how to transform this xml based on the value of Attributes/Attribute/Type

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Data Schema="XML A">
  <Attributes type="Common">
    <Attr id="" name="Buyer ID" value="Lee" />
    <Attr id="" name="Enviornment" value="Development" />
    <Attr id="" name="Retail" value="" />
    <Attr id="" name="PlusShip" value="False" />
 </Attributes>
 <Attributes type="Category">
   <Attr id="" name="Gender" value="Men" />
   <Attr id="" name="HeelHeight" value="" />
 </Attributes>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following stylesheet produces the desired result:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Data Schema="XML A">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Data>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Attribute[not(Type=following::Type)]">
        <Attributes type="{Type}">
            <xsl:for-each select="../Attribute[Type=current()/Type]">
               <Attr id="{id}" name="{Name}" value="{Value}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Attributes>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Attribute"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output on your source document:

```
<Data Schema="XML A">
    <Attributes type="category">
        <Attr id="402" name="Gender" value="Men"/>
        <Attr id="433" name="HeelHeight" value=""/>
    </Attributes>
    <Attributes type="common">
        <Attr id="5" name="Buyer ID" value="Lee"/>
        <Attr id="331" name="Enviornment" value="Development"/>
        <Attr id="79" name="Retail" value=""/>
        <Attr id="41" name="PlusShip" value="False"/>
    </Attributes>
</Data>
```

**Edit:** OK, let's get rid of that ugly `for-each`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Data Schema="XML A">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Data>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Attribute[not(Type=following::Type)]">
        <Attributes type="{Type}">
            <xsl:apply-templates 
                 select="../Attribute[Type=current()/Type]" mode="out"/>
        </Attributes>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Attribute" mode="out">
        <Attr id="{id}" name="{Name}" value="{Value}"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Attribute"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I feel much better.

**Edit #2:** Using the Muenchian Method (with sorting):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="type" match="Attribute" use="Type"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Data Schema="XML A">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="XML/Attributes/Attribute">
                 <xsl:sort select="Type" order="descending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </Data>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template 
            match="Attribute[generate-id()=generate-id(key('type', Type)[1])]">
        <Attributes type="{Type}">
            <xsl:apply-templates 
                    select="../Attribute[Type=current()/Type]" mode="out"/>
        </Attributes>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Attribute" mode="out">
         <Attr id="{id}" name="{Name}" value="{Value}"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Attribute"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces the following (ordered) output:

```
<Data Schema="XML A">
    <Attributes type="common">
        <Attr id="5" name="Buyer ID" value="Lee"/>
        <Attr id="331" name="Enviornment" value="Development"/>
        <Attr id="79" name="Retail" value=""/>
        <Attr id="41" name="PlusShip" value="False"/>
    </Attributes>
    <Attributes type="category">
        <Attr id="402" name="Gender" value="Men"/>
        <Attr id="433" name="HeelHeight" value=""/>
   </Attributes>
</Data>
```

Comment: One more question. How I can sort in a that I will get this first <Attributes type="common"> instead of <Attributes type="category">. I have tried using the following xsl:sort but it is not working.
<xsl:sort select="Type" order="descending"/>                                             Any ideas ...

Comment: @lwburk: Correct indeed. But grouping with the old "I have no preceding equal" instead of "I'm the first of a kind" with Muenchian method?

Comment: @Alejandro - I know. Shameful.

Comment: @Alejandro - Added an attempt at the Muenchian Method.

Comment: @user662877 - See my latest edit, which adds sorting (and might be a little faster, too).

Comment: +++ for solution. Thanks Iwburk.

Comment: Now I have to check for the particular/required element if it is not present or it's value in NULL then create a new element dynamically. However this element should be outside of the current element (Attribute) How can I do this. For example in the above XML if <Name> = Buyer ID then check the <value> of the current <Attribute> if it is empty. Then create this <errorCodes>
            <errorCode>"value for Buyer ID is missing."</errorCode></errorCodes> Thanks

Comment: I'm using for-each and checking the value of required elements. Like below... How can I incorporate this in the above XSLT.         <xsl:if test="Name = 'Retail'">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="Value = ''">
      <errorCode>
       <xsl:value-of select ="'&quot;value for Retail is missing.&quot;'"/>
      </errorCode>
     </xsl:when>
   </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:if>

Comment: @JohnXsl - Thanks for asking this in a separate question. That's a much better way to get noticed :)